# install R binary package with dependencies

Tags: r, r-package

**Short question**

I am building a package `foo`. I want to distribute the binary package for `foo`. Does installing the binary package using the following command automatically install the dependencies? Is there a way to distribute the binary package so that the users don't have to explicitly install dependencies?

```
install.packages("foo_1.0.zip", type="win.binary", dependencies=TRUE)
```

**details:**

I am using R4.2.2 on Windows.

I build the package using:

```
R CMD INSTALL --build foo
```

resulting in `foo_1.0.zip

`foo` depends on the package `collections`.

`DESCRIPTION` file contains the following line `Imports: collections(>= 0.3.6)`

`NAMESPACE` File contains the following line:
`importFrom(collections, dict)`

If a user doesn't have the package `collections` installed, and tries to install `foo` on Windows using `install.packages("foo_1.0.zip", type="win.binary", dependencies=TRUE)`, the package `collections` is not automatically installed but the installation for `foo` succeeds without any error. When the user tries to use it with `library(foo)`, they get the following error because of the importFrom line in NAMESPACE.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'foo' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called 'collections'
```

I don't plan to distribute the package on CRAN.

Comment: R can do all this for you, as it does on CRAN _and on other repositories_. You can hold all the (added) dependencies in a local repository.  Many of us managed such repositories in labs or workplaces. I wrote a helper package too I (and many others) find useful:  [drat](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat)

Comment: Normally to install from a local file you need to set `repos=NULL` in `install.packages()`. Since `repos` is NULL it cannot automatically install dependencies for you in that case. I'm surprised it worked without it but I don't have a Windows machines to test with.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel so I get that there is no "ready" way to do this directly using install.packages(). EIther you hold the dependencies in your package (using some scripts_ or manually install those. Am I right in saying that?
MrFlick That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Try `devtools::install_local("mypackage.tar.gz")`  That will install the source package in the indicated file and all dependencies from CRAN.

Comment: No that is not at all what I am saying. You can set up a repo containing source (or binary, if you build them) packages B, C, D, and E that your package A depends upon. (Of course you install A in the repo.) Then, `install.packages("A")` will install all of them, "automagically", if you declare the dependencies (as you would at CRAN).  And `drat` helps you put that repository together.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks Dirk. Many of your answers have helped me a lot!
@Grothendieck, thanks. It works too, fantastic solution.